# Leaflet turf.buffer: projection problem

Tags: leaflet, turf

I'm trying to make a buffer with Leafler, Turf, work out of the drawnItems of Leaflet Draw; but the result isn't right. It's too high but not large enough. Could you help me fix it?[image]

I'm using this button to get the custom buffer value:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="15"><button onclick="myFunction()">Disabled buffer</button>
```

the script that call it is:

```
var x, myFunction, data, features, buffered, bufferedLayer;
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("number").value;
var xdiv = x/100;
var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
  var buffered = turf.buffer(data, xdiv,{units: 'kilometers'});
        var bufferedLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
        bufferedLayer.addData(buffered);
            drawnItems.addLayer(bufferedLayer); 
               bufferedLayer.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG4326;   
        bufferedLayer.addTo(map);
 }
```

Comment: @TomazicM It may be an error. I  changed it

Comment: What is your map projection?

Comment: @TomazicM  it is still leaflet default, 3857, mercator (also named 900913 like I sometimes see it)

Comment: The code above cannot be the reason for described problem, see simple JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/zoc6vxjd/

Comment: But there is a clear situation, that could cause it. Leaflet uses `[lat, lng]` coordinate order, but GeoJSON uses `[lng, lat]` order. If you would feed Leaflet coordinate to `turf.buffer` method and then take result and swap coordinates for each polygon coordinate, you would get vertically flattened circle. Reason for this is that buffer coordinates would be calculated nearer to equator, where meridians are further apart. When then moved back to north where meridians are closer together, this would cause horizontal squeeze of circle polygon.

Comment: See JSFiddle for the above described case: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/6vgrsqLu/

Comment: @TomazicM thank you. I tidied my code until the last bit, to find that I was using a previous version of turf.min.js (2) that had a bug with buffers.

Comment: Yes, I knew about that but forgot about id since I'm using the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The egg-shaped buffer is a known bug to Turf.min.js on older versions, especially version 2, that I used.

Switched to turf.min.js version 6 and solved the problem.